# how to fix bug in changing position with mouse of box in Aframe

Tags: aframe

I change the position of the object when I press the wheel and move the mouse.

But if I move the mouse between 2 clicks of the wheel, the position of the box is reset.

do you have any idea?
i would like that when i click on the wheel and move the mouse, the box move from where he is to an other place.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rotation, Zoom et Déplacement</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    AFRAME.registerComponent('drag-rotate-move-component', {
      schema: {
        speed: { default: 4 },
        zoomSpeed: { default: 0.5 },
        moveSpeed: { default: 0.01 } // Ajout de la vitesse de déplacement
      },
      init: function () {
        this.ifMouseDown = false;
        this.ifMiddleMouseDown = false; // Nouvelle variable pour le clic du milieu
        this.x_cord = 0;
        this.y_cord = 0;
        this.targetPosition = new THREE.Vector3(); // Nouvelle variable pour la position de l'élément
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.OnDocumentMouseDown.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.OnDocumentMouseUp.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.OnDocumentMouseMove.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('wheel', this.OnDocumentMouseWheel.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }); // Désactive le menu contextuel
      },
      OnDocumentMouseDown: function (event) {
        if (event.button === 0) {
          this.ifMouseDown = true;
          this.x_cord = event.clientX;
          this.y_cord = event.clientY;
        } else if (event.button === 1) {
          this.ifMiddleMouseDown = true;
        }
      },
      OnDocumentMouseUp: function (event) {
        if (event.button === 0) {
          this.ifMouseDown = false;
        } else if (event.button === 1) {
          this.ifMiddleMouseDown = false;
        }
      },
      OnDocumentMouseMove: function (event) {
        if (this.ifMouseDown) {
          var temp_x = event.clientX - this.x_cord;
          var temp_y = event.clientY - this.y_cord;
          if (Math.abs(temp_y) < Math.abs(temp_x)) {
            this.el.object3D.rotateY(temp_x * this.data.speed / 1000);
          } else {
            this.el.object3D.rotateX(temp_y * this.data.speed / 1000);
          }
          this.x_cord = event.clientX;
          this.y_cord = event.clientY;
        } else if (this.ifMiddleMouseDown) {
          // Déplacement lorsque le clic du milieu est enfoncé
          var deltaX = event.clientX - this.x_cord;
          var deltaY = event.clientY - this.y_cord;
          this.x_cord = event.clientX;
          this.y_cord = event.clientY;

          // Convertit le mouvement de la souris en déplacement dans la scène
          var distance = this.el.object3D.position.distanceTo(this.targetPosition);
          var factor = distance / 500; // Ajustez ce facteur selon vos besoins
          var moveX = deltaX * factor;
          var moveY = deltaY * factor;

          // Met à jour la position cible
        this.el.object3D.position.x += moveX;
        this.el.object3D.position.y -= moveY; // Inversé pour correspondre à la direction du mouvement de la souris
        }
      },
      OnDocumentMouseWheel: function (event) {
        var delta = event.deltaY;
        var scale = 1 + delta * this.data.zoomSpeed / 1000;
        this.el.object3D.scale.multiplyScalar(scale);
      }
    });
  </script>

  <a-scene>
    <a-box id="b1" color="green" position="2 2 -3" drag-rotate-move-component></a-box>
    <a-box id="b2" color="blue" position="-2 2 -3"></a-box>
    <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled:false">
      <a-cursor></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
  </a-scene>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend updating to latest A-Frame version 1.5.0 and also provide full runnable code. It will be much easier for people to help. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great. Best of luck

Comment: It's the full runnable code.

Comment: Better to provide a link where people can run the code and suggest alternatives directly. The easier you make it the more chances to get help. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great. best of luck

Comment: here you can run the code : https://codepen.io/karl-thomas-the-looper/pen/vYPGmJW

Comment: I would edit your original question and add the link there. also glitch is more simple / cleaner and easier to provide working solutions. best of luck

Comment: Lastly. notice you're in a very old version of A-Frame. Use 1.5.0

Comment: you could edit original question and add link.